# Is this proof valid for integration

Tags: integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals, proof-explanation, geometric-series

I came across this proof that the definite integral $\displaystyle \int x^k \, dx=\frac{x^k+1}{k+1}$. The proof sums up many rectangles which are below the the curve (the lower sum), with the limit that the number of rectangles tends to infinte.

https://plus.maths.org/content/intriguing-integrals-part-i

Please have a look at the link.

I was wondering if this proof was valid as it only considers the lower sum. I attempted to prove it for the upper sum, but did not come out with the same expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends in the definition of ***integral*** you have. I refer to the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* of W. Rudin.

In my words... We define the *Lower integral* as the "limit" of the lower sums, and the *Upper integral* as the "limit" of the upper sums. When that limits are equal we say that the *Definite integral* corresponds to that limit. 
I put quotation marks because I'm not very strict in say just limit.

In this case I think is valid to only prove with the lower limit because the function satisfy the conditions for be integrable; but if we want to be more strict (and if, in hypothesis, you don't know the conditions under a function is integrable) we need to prove that the limit of the upper sums is equal to the limit of the lower sums.